# Changing the bit rate of an MP3 bitrate on Android without ffmpeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg, mp3, bitrate

In my project, I have a 320kbps MP3 that is quite large. Since it's so big, I'd like to convert it to use a lower bit rate (about 80kbps). 
I know that the `ffmpeg` library exists to do this, but using `ffmpeg` in Android is very complex.

Is there another way to change the MP3 bit rate that does not use `ffmpeg` in Android?

Comment: Why do you need to change the bitrate programmatically in Android? I mean, isn't it easier to alter it using some desktop application instead.

Comment: I know there are many Desktop apps to do this, such as MP3 Bitrate Changer (it's very cool). But in my app, i need to send a mp3 file to server, the problem is "If mp3 size is large, It can take alot of time and bandwidth of server". So I want to change mp3 size down to smaller. It is my idea . Tks for your replying

Comment: ffmpeg is your best bet. There's not a standard Android/Java class to do this, at least not that I know of.